# EF: Foreign key to multiple Tables

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a table holding translation data. Each row has the `EntityID` and `EntityType` in order to know for which entity this translation is.

Translation table

- id
- entityId
- entityTypeId
- description

If `entityTypeId = 1` then is a Film with `Film.id = entityId`

If `entityTypeId = 2` then is a Car with `Car.id = entityId` etc.

I am using `EntityFramework` Core (code first) and I would like to have this result. In my entities, I have included the following:

> public virtual IList Translations { get; set; }

so, EF has created columns for each one of my entities which is normal, but not that I want.

Translation table created by EF

- id
- entityId
- entityTypeId
- description
- filmId // I don't want this
- carId // I don't want this

Is there any way to achieve this?

Code
Film Table

```
    [Table("Film")]
    public class Film
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Points { get; set; }

        public IList<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
    }
```

Car Table

```
    [Table("Car")]
    public class Car
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Doors { get; set; }

        public IList<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
    }
```

Translation Table

```
    [Table("Translation")]
    public class Translation
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid EntityId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid EntityTypeId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid LanguageId { get; set; }



        public Language Language { get; set; }

        public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
    }
```

Also, I may have **more than one** translations for a car or a film

Comment: Show us all the EF code please. You might also want to look at this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: This type of question appears very often. If you know that it's about *polymorphic association* you'll quickly find other posts. And get discouraged to do it this way.

Comment: @Train I edited the question, provided code of my tables.